# c# stringbuilder vs Aggreggate?

Tags: c#, .net

Is StringBuilder really faster than Aggreggate?

> ```
>     string c = tmpArr[0].Aggregate(string.Empty, (current, m) => current + (m.Name + " "));
>
>     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
>
>     foreach (Mobile m in tmpArr[0])
>         sb.Append(m.Name + " ");
>
>     sb.ToString();
> ```

which of those two is faster? aggregate certainly is cleaner, but is it fast or is it the same as doing

> foreach(Mobile m in tmpArr[0])
>       c += m.Name + " ";

what I really would like to do is something like string.Join(",",tmpArr[0]), but I don't want it to concat their ToString values, just their Names, how would I do that best?

my problem with not using string.Join is I would actually have to do something like this:

> string separator = "";
>           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
>
> ```
>     foreach (Mobile m in tmpArr[0])
>     {
>         separator = ", ";
>         sb.Append(separator + m.Name);
>     }
> ```

Comment: Minor point: your final example is incorrect... the `separator = ", ";` should be *after* the Append, otherwise it will set before it's first use, which is not your intention

Comment: It's your code, test it yourself, using your hardware, and your data :)

Comment: string.Join(", ", tmpArr[0].Select(m=> m.Name));

Comment: OR `String.Join(", ",tmpArr[0].Select(m=>m.Name))`

Comment: [If you have two horses and you want to know which of the two is the faster then race your horses. Don't write short descriptions of the horses, post them on the Internet, and ask random strangers to guess which is faster!](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: ...you called out your own question for being an exact duplicate?  Why would you post the same question again, especially when the other one was answered?

Comment: What happened here? The other one seems to be worded exactly the same, with the same code, however it is two years old. miley, did you copy / paste this old question?

Comment: What is even going on here

Comment: This `sb.Append(m.Name + " ");` is wrong. You are manually composing strings (`m.Name + " "`). Do `sb.Append(m.Name); sb.Append(" ");`

Answer (score 1):

Is a bad idea to multiple time add chunks to a string, because since string are immutable in .NET you obtain a lot of garbaged string in memory, and probably that dublication is more expensive in term of execution time too. Using `StringBuilder`, `String.Concat()`, or `String.Join()` are definitely the best way when you need to compose strings.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way to do this is to use `String.Join`, because that's what it is there for:

```
string.Join(" ", tmpArr[0].Select(x => x.Name));
```